# ObservableCollection operation error

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am getting error when using foreach with ObservableCollection.

Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

How should I handle this error?

Comment: Don't modify the collection while enumerating. Try putting a `.ToArray()` after the collection in the `foreach` loop. Next time, also post your code please.

Comment: `How should I handle this error?` it depends on your case. a problem can be handled in many ways.

Comment: I am not sure it is best practice.
Anyway I resolved by decreasing index backward.